# How to add the client ip in request header in fiddler

Tags: header, fiddler, x-forwarded-for

I am using fiddler as a reverse proxy, I want to forward the client ip in the request header so that the server can get it like this:

```
oSession.oRequest["X-Forwarded-For"]=;
```

But I don't know the variable name that I should set, can anyone help me with this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
oSession.oRequest["X-Forwarded-For"]=oSession.oFlags["X-ClientIP"]
```